# Problems with my monitor - Image is moving

Tags: display

I got a monitor from UK but it has a problem and I don't know what can cause it.

It's hard to tell ( for me ) so I made a small video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6wzjgBXjXs&feature=youtu.be

It's working with an adaptor. I didn't get the one that was made for it so I bought an universal laptop charger. ( From 12v to 24v ~ 5A ). The monitor required 12V ~4.5A so it's good.

I try it a few days ago, the problem came up after 1 day, so I remove it and place the old monitor back. 2 Days ago I give a try again but after one day same problem came uo

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a few photos instead, *and* please try to describe the problem in the title for otherwise this question is useless for future visitors (and then: would actually be off-topic). Success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power supply you bought does not filter the power cleanly enough.  Buy a better one, preferably the one intended for the monitor.  That should fix your problem.  (I used to fix computers for a living.)

Comment: Umm, I was hoping that not the power supply is the problem but that's it. Thanks